# Passing Select Option value

Tags: apex, selectlist

I have the following drop down, and I want to send the value of the selected file to my controller .. so if the user selects parent account1 my controller should get that value or if they select parent account2 same thing 
VF

```
 <label>Select the Region</label>
                </td>
                <td class="data2Col" style="border-bottom:0px;">
                    <select id="sandler" class="sandler" value="{!regionAccount}">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value='ParentAccount1'>asdf--zz</option>
            <option value='ParentAccount2'>ggggg</option>

        </select>
        </td>
```

controller

```
// Recieve the Region Value from Visual Force Page.. 
   public String regionAccount{get;set;}
    public Account regionAccountId{get;set;}
// if regional is not empty 
if (regionAccount != Null ){


      // get the value of region and find the accountId
        regionAccountId = [select Id  from Account where Name = : regionAccount];
        account.ParentId =regionAccountId.Id;


        }
        else{
        for (Contact parents : parentAccount)
        {
            System.debug('Now I get to here part 2');
            account.ParentId = parents.AccountId;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these are html tags so you can't directly pass the value in controller so I suggest you to first get this in javascript

```
<script>
function passValue()
{
     var e = document.getElementById("sandler");
     var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
     actfun(strUser);
}
</script>
```

then using actionfunction pass this in controller.

```
<apex:actionfunction name="actfun" action="{!contmethod}" rerender="frm"
       <apex:param name="param" value="" assignTo="{!contVar}" />
</apex:actionfunction>
```

Comment: thank you for respond, can you explain to me , what would  {!contVar} is. I have seen many example but i dont understand where this value exist .. like [SelectOption](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_selectoption.htm) What is !item, !item doesnt exist in the controller

Comment: also what is actfun(strUser); ... where is that strUser come from ?

Comment: @bez here struser is select option which is selected by user so onchange just call this method and see the action. contVar is just a reference of public controller variable which you can use here. Hope this make things clear to you.

Comment: Am I suppose to make a public String contVar {get;set;} in my controller

Comment: @bez yes. and in your method you will get updated values.